# Google App Engine YAML not finding php in directories

Tags: google-app-engine

My App Engine isn't loading php files in sub directory

Directory Structure is from the app.yaml file to the corresponding files.

I'm using Google's App Engine with PHP and my YAML code is below

```
handlers:

- url: /
  script: soap/index.php   

- url: /(.+)
  script: soap/index.php

- url: /getGEO.php
  script: soap/getGEO.php


- url: /tests/XML_GEOOffers.php
  script: soap/tests/XML_GEOOffers.php   "No handlers matched this URL."

- url: /tests/test.php
  script: soap/tests/test.php           "No handlers matched this URL."
```

I also having problem to past the parameters for GET in url

`localhost:11080/trace`    ( my script shows false as no paramter sent )

but when i past the parameters into url, it shows blank page instead for true or false

```
localhost:11080/trace?Pub=0&Adv=0&SDK=0&HWD=c45f9a729cd349bdf3f21e96d305afde1028be99&OS=0&AV=nothing|nothing&BROWSER=IE&Sub=0&campaign=0&Demo=0
```

I'd greatly appreciate if anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `/` last, else it matches every url.  Same for your `/(.+)` handler.  Try this order:

```
handlers:

- url: /getGEO.php
  script: soap/getGEO.php


- url: /tests/XML_GEOOffers.php
  script: soap/tests/XML_GEOOffers.php   #"No handlers matched this URL."

- url: /tests/test.php
  script: soap/tests/test.php           #"No handlers matched this URL."  

- url: /(.+)
  script: soap/index.php

- url: /
  script: soap/index.php
```

You don't really need one of the last two, as they point to the same place.